# Haskell. "Could not deduce (t ~ [t]) from the context (Eq t)"

Tags: haskell

Just learn the haskell by myself, and can not solve this problem. These are the codes.

```
subst :: Eq t=>t->t->[t]->[t]
subst a b [xs]=[if x==a then b else x | x <- xs]
```

The error is below.

```
subst.hs:2:46:
    Could not deduce (t ~ [t])
    from the context (Eq t)
      bound by the type signature for
                 subst :: Eq t => t -> t -> [t] -> [t]
      at subst.hs:1:10-29
      ‘t’ is a rigid type variable bound by
          the type signature for subst :: Eq t => t -> t -> [t] -> [t]
          at subst.hs:1:10
    Relevant bindings include
      xs :: t (bound at subst.hs:2:12)
      b :: t (bound at subst.hs:2:9)
      a :: t (bound at subst.hs:2:7)
      subst :: t -> t -> [t] -> [t] (bound at subst.hs:2:1)
    In the expression: xs
    In a stmt of a list comprehension: x <- xs
```

The problem, I guess, is that haskell can not ensure the element from [t] match the t. I am not sure. And I want to know how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you just have one `[..]` wrap to many:

```
subst :: Eq t=>t->t->[t]->[t]
subst a b xs = [if x==a then b else x | x <- xs]
```

it's just `xs` not `[xs]`

The reason is simple: if you write `[xs]` you tell Haskell to expect a list with an single entry `xs` and it will try to *pattern-match* it - after this you tell it to pull out values `x` from `xs` (`x <- xs`) that tells Haskell that `xs` has to be some kind of list itself. so in the end it will assume `t` to be some list `t ~ [s]`. But then you go on and check `x == a` and here `x :: s` and `a :: t` ending with the error as now `[s] ~ t ~ s`.

Answer (score 3):

In your parameter list you write `[xs]`. This is a pattern that matches a list containing exactly one element, which will then be referred to as `xs`. This has two consequences:

1. This is a non-exhaustive pattern match, which will fail at run time if the given list has zero elements or more than one. Since you want the same code to execute, regardless of the list's length, you want a pattern that always matches, like `xs` without the brackets.
2. Since the `xs` in `[xs]` refers to a single element of the list, its type is `t`, not `[t]`. However you use it as if its type were `[t]`, which leads Haskell to conclude that `t` must equal `[t]` (the `~` operator is used in Haskell to denote that two types are equal), which leads to the somewhat confusing type error you're getting.